# Installing gcovr on debian 7

Tags: ubuntu, debian-wheezy

On ubuntu 13.10 I can install gcovr just fine: `sudo apt-get install gcovr` But on debian 7 I get:

```
# apt-get install gcovr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcovr
```

How do I install gcovr on debian 7 which I need for this:

http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/continuous-code-coverage-with-gcc-googletest-and-hudson/

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if installing using pip instead:

```
# pip install gcovr
Downloading/unpacking gcovr
  Downloading gcovr-3.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/gcovr/setup.py) egg_info for package gcovr

Installing collected packages: gcovr
  Running setup.py install for gcovr
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/gcovr.bak from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/gcovr from 644 to 755

    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/gcovr.bak to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/tmp to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/gcovr to 755
Successfully installed gcovr
Cleaning up...
```